# Compare Wordpress Tags with Post Content and output

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, compare

OK Wordpress PHP gods, here is a good one.  I want to compare the TAGS against the Post Content, if the TAG appears in the Post Content, then I want it to output.  If it doesn't appear in the content, then don't.

1. I am presuming that I would need to output the TAGS as an Array
2. If I do the same for the Content, using (correct if incorrect) 'Explode' then each word would be single. Consider 'The Lazy Brown Fox', if I had a TAG 'Brown Fox'

So in short I am stumpped, and have no idea how to proceed.  I am VERY sure that this post would interest many people.

Many thanks for your advice in advance

Stu

Comment: What about tag "Lazy Fox" - do you consider it to be in content or not?

Comment: If it would be clearer what you want, it could interest even more people. You want to display all tags in lets say the tag cloud, that are also written in the post text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than exploding the words in the post, why not use strpos()? This would take care of the multiple word tags.

```
$tags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
$stripped = strtolower(strip_tags($post->post_content));
$tags_to_output = array();
foreach($tags as $tag){
    if (strpos($stripped, strtolower($tag->name)) !== false){
        $tags_to_output[] = $tag;
    }
}
```

If you were really worried about it you could replace multiple whitespace characters in `$stripped`

Comment: This looks promising and how stupid am I for not thinking of it.  I will give it a whirl.  Thanks Chris.

Comment: Got that working great, do you think it would be possible to add some complication in?  Images that are attached to the post and the name/title of the image.  output the array results from the last job and then run again like the above.

When you leant arrays did you get it all straight away or did it 'click' one day?

Comment: Got it working just got to merge the two outputs into one.  Thank you again Chris for getting there on this one.